# FFT spike at 0 Hz from Accelerometer Data

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft, accelerometer

I recently generated accelerometer data for x, y, z, based on vibration from a machine.
Is there a reason why the FFT I attempted to generate from this analysis only has one peak at 0 Hz? Is there something wrong with my code that is producing this result?

[Accelerometer Graph, X_t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6F0G.png)

Here is the script I wrote to generate the FFT, and the result:

```
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
N = 1192
yf = fft(x)
xf = fftfreq(N,1/5)[0:1191] 

plt.plot(xf, np.abs(yf))

plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.title("FFT on X direction")
```

[FFT from accelerometer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjDGh.png)

Comment: I mean, from the data it seems obvious that there is a very strong DC component. Filter out the 0 frequency and plot the rest, just to fix the scale of the plot. Log scale may also help

Comment: The peak at 0 corresponds to the sum of your data values. Subtract the mean from the signal to get rid of that peak. Other than that, your signal looks mostly like noise. You might have a somewhat stronger component in the first few bins next to the 0 bin.

Comment: 0Hz peak is gravity.

Comment: It must have a DC offset - it is not level. Maybe get the spectrum after subtracting the average.